# tkcalender object not showing in exe created by cx_freeze

Tags: tkinter, cx-freeze

I have created a GUI using `tkinter` which uses `tkcalender` Calender and `Dateentry`.
The program runs successfully with python without any issues.
When I am converting it to exe using `cx_freeze` process is successful with no errors.
However, when I launch the exe, program runs without any error but `tkcalender` objects are not displayed.
I have tried adding `tkcalender` manually to executables in the setup file with no success.

Anyone who can help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution.

I used console version of cx_freeze setup.py to check that what was going wrong.

It was showing - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘babel.numbers’.

So I included 'babel.numbers' manually in the packages in cx_freeze setup.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have created exe using pyinstaller, and my GUI also has a calender widget and its showing in the UI without any issues.

Try using

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --noconsole -F pythoncode.py
```

Comment: I am using cx_freeze so this solution doesn't work for me. However, I found that tkcalender documentation explicitly mentions the problem related to babel module import with pyinstaller here - https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howtos.html

Comment: do a --hidden import [babel.numbers] this works for me in .spec file of pyinstaller